# Python: Checking for JSON files and creating one if needed

Tags: python

I'm currently making a program that requires a JSON database file. I want the program to check for the file, if it's there then it's perfect, run the rest of the program, but if it doesn't exist create 'Accounts.json' with `{}` inside the file, instead then run the program.

How would I do this? Whats the most efficient way.

Note: I use this for checking, but how would I create the file:

```
def startupCheck():
    if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
        # checks if file exists
        print ("File exists and is readable")
    else:
        print ("Either file is missing or is not readable")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you could simply do:

```
import io
import json
import os

def startupCheck():
    if os.path.isfile(PATH) and os.access(PATH, os.R_OK):
        # checks if file exists
        print ("File exists and is readable")
    else:
        print ("Either file is missing or is not readable, creating file...")
        with io.open(os.path.join(PATH, 'Accounts.json'), 'w') as db_file:
            db_file.write(json.dumps({}))
```

Comment: @Styvane
I edited the answer for using `io` (which also accepts an `encoding` argument if needed) because it works in both python2 and python3. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

This is how i did it. I hope it helps.
edit, yeey it looks like a code now :D

```
import json
import os

def where_json(file_name):
    return os.path.exists(file_name)


if where_json('data.json'):
    pass

else:

    data = {  
        'user': input('User input: '),
        'pass': input('Pass input: ')
    }


    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:  
        json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 4):

How about wrapping the open file in a try/except? I'm not a professional Python coder, so feel free to weigh in if this is not a kosher approach.

```
try:
    with open('Accounts.json', 'r') as fp:
        accounts = json.load(fp)

except IOError:
    print('File not found, will create a new one.')
    accounts = {}

# do stuff with your data...
with open('Accounts.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(accounts, fp, indent=4)
```

Comment: Do the upvoted answers above not do the same?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough - the code should be fine.

Answer (score -3):

`w+` opens with write permissions.
The `+` creates a new file if one is not found.

```
filename = 'jsonDB.json'

def openFile():
    with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
    f.write('{}')            
    f.close

openFile()
```

Comment: This answer is of very poor quality: explanation of modes is not correct, code is not properly indented, f.close (correctly: f.close()) is not required when using with.